# Send message using MSMQ between two EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, msmq

I have two Amazon EC2 instances and I want to send a message from one server to the MSMQ on the other. Normally, in other test environments, this would be on a domain so wouldn't be a problem, but these EC2 instances are workgroup computers and not on a domain. Therefore, trying to send to  a public queue on that machine isn't possible. I've therefore created a private queue on the second server, but can't see how to get the message to appear. I've tried the following:

> [machinename][queuename] e.g. ServerB\testqueue
>
> FormatName:direct=[machinename]\private$[queuename] e.g. FormatName:direct=ServerB\private$\testqueue
>
> DIRECT=[machinename]\PRIVATE$[queuename] e.g. DIRECT=ServerB\private$\testqueue
>
> FormatName:direct=os:[machinename]\PRIVATE$[queuename] e.g. FormatName:direct=os:ServerB\private$\testqueue

*Note: I have host file entries for both servers listing the workgroup/netbios names against the relevant fixed EC2 IP addresses*

Using the two FormatName: entries, I do not get any errors but the messages never arrive. Using the others give me an error regarding the format name. On the private queues I have given 'everyone' full control.

Can anyone advise on how I can send a message from one EC2 windows server to a private queue (not on a domain) on another?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> On the private queues I have given 'everyone' full control.

This catches out a lot of people. "Everyone" does not mean everyone anymore - that was changed years ago. "Everyone" means all the accounts that the local security system has access to. An account on a different workgroup machine is unknown to it and so you need to add "Anonymous Logon" to really get everyone.

> Using the two FormatName: entries, I do not get any errors but the messages never arrive

To see errors, you need to enable negative source journaling and check the dead letter queue for the information.

Comment: This should be the approved answer. We added the computer management snap in to mmc, went to msmq, then to the private queue, opened properties and on the security tab, gave anonymous read access. Seems we can also set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security` to `NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient` via powershell, which we'll try during automation.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be the 'accepted answer' - but if you fail to find your way you can use AWS hosted queue implementation - [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).
It is not 1-1 compatible with MSMQ but it is a valid fallback strategy (and 1 thing less to manage).